# List of fonts available in gvim

Tags: vim, macvim

I know I can set fonts for gvim using something like `set guifont=Menlo\ Regular:h14`. I have the following questions

1. Is there a wiki where I can see what all fonts are supported?
2. I want to set my font to "Lucida Sans Typewriter". I tried `set guifont=Lucida Sans Typewriter\ Regular:h14`, but it gave me an error when I opened a file using gvim. Error is "E518: Unknown option: Sans"
3. I also tried to increase the font size using `set guifont=Sans\ Regular:h14`, but looks like it is stuck at font size 11. I am trying this on macvim.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

1. You need to backslash all of the spaces in the font name, not just the last one.
2. You can `:set guifont=*` to open a font chooser with the fonts available on your system. Then after you pick one you like you can `:set guifont?` to read back the value you need to put in your `.vimrc`.

Comment: Thank you. Point 1 works. However, I opened a gvim window and typed `:set guifont=*`, it did open a font chooser and I picked one. When I `set guifont=?` it says `E596: Invalid font(s): guifont=?`.

Comment: @user376507 sorry, typo :)

Comment: After choosing the font you like, you can edit your vimrc file (or your gvimrc file, if you have one) and, in Insert mode, enter `set guifont=<C-R>=&gfn<CR><Esc>`.  (You will have to escape the spaces, or you could use `set guifont=<C-R>=escape(&gfn, ' ')<CR><Esc>`.)

Comment: Do the fonts have to be formally installed  installed on Windows (I don't have admin rigths on my machine)? Or can they be in AppLocal somewhere?